# wxWidgets about append menuItems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm a newer to wxWidgets. My wxWidgets version: wxWidgets-2.8.12, codeblocks: 12.11, in minGW.

My code is:

```
item=new wxMenuItem(settings,id,wxT("showTip"),wxT(""),wxITEM_CHECK );
item->Check(true);
settings->Append(item);/* after Append to 'settings', item->IsChecked()==false. */
```

First I create a menuItem and set the check-status to 'true'. And then add to the menu.
And a strange thing happens, the check-status is changed to 'false'. 
please tell me why?

By the way, this is my test code for this question.

```
wxMenu *settings=new wxMenu;
wxMenuItem *item=new wxMenuItem(settings,menuID_MENU,wxT("test menu"),wxT("help message"),wxITEM_CHECK);
item->Check(true);
bool check_status=item->IsChecked();
settings->Append(item);
bool check_status_after=item->IsChecked();

if(check_status!=check_status_after)
    wxLogMessage(wxT("not equal"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell why it's implemented this way, but the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu_item.html#afcfbb12e302c0528e55efcb1c6f5f7fc) indicates that `Check` "only works when the item is already appended to a menu."

Internally (on Windows), `IsChecked` will check whether it's appended to a menu; if so, it grabs the `Checked` state from that, otherwise it will return the value of a flag it stores itself. That's why the result changes when you `Append` the item.

Swapping the `Check` and `Append` lines should be a straightforward workaround.

Comment: Yes, that right! I ignored that important indication. Thanks.